# The path to the driver executable must be set by the web driver.gecko.driver system property; Nightwatch

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I tried to setup Nightwatch.js in on My Windows 8 machine

I installed nodejs,nightwatch and selenium-standalone-sever 3.0.0-beta1.jar.
When i try to run my sample.js test i get the following error.

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ state: 'unhandled error',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 847580505,
  value:
   { localizedMessage: 'The path to the driver executable must be set by the web
driver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.co
m/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.
com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases',
     cause: null,
     suppressed: [],
     message: 'The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ge
cko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla
/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozil
la/geckodriver/releases',
     hCode: 294316877,
     class: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException',
     screen: null },
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 13 }
```

My config file is :

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" :"",
  "custom_assertions_path" :"",
  "page_objects_path" :"",
  "globals_path":"",
  "selenium": {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my sample.js file is :

```
 module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .windowMaximize()
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired capabilities should be like below, ***but I am not sure if nightwatch js supports webdriver 3.0 or not***.

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "marionette": true
      }
```

And cli_arguments should have path for geckodriver.

```
"cli_args" : {
     "webdriver.gecko.driver": "<path-to-geckodriver>"
 }
```

You can download geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

For more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

You haven't started selenium server. You can do that manually or nightwatch can do that for you

`"selenium": {
    "start_process" : true, // let nigthwatch to start selenium server
    "server_path" : "./selenium-server-standalone.jar",  // provide path to selenium server jar
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install geckodriver
```

then you change your driver to firefox by

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
}
```